# jQuery function associated with Bootstrap button is executed only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm following a tutorial using Bootstrap 3. So far so good, except for a non-expected behavior: when I click a button associated with a jQuery function, the alert gets displayed fine. However, once I dismiss it, clicking the button again doesn't do anything, that is, looks like it's a no-op.

For brevity, I'll include the relevant sections. I have the following `<div>`:

```
    <div class="row" id="bigCallout">
        <div class="col-12">

            <div class="alert alert-success alert-block fade in" id="successAlert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                <h4>Success!</h4>
                <p>You just made this element display using jQuery.</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div> <!-- end bigCallout -->
```

Below I include my JS file:

```
<!-- Custom JS -->
<script src="includes/js/script.js"></script>
```

The JS file mentioned above contains this only function:

```
$(function() {

   $('#alertMe').click(function(e) {

       e.preventDefault();

       $('#successAlert').slideDown();

   });

});
```

Why is the function being executed only the first time the button is clicked? Thanks!

Comment: And no error in the Dev console?

Comment: No error. Please see Jason's response, which explains why it was behaving the way it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you rely on the `data-dismiss="alert"` which dismisses/closes the alert, the alert is actually removed from the data model. Therefore, when you click to attempt to `slideDown` the element again, that element no longer exists.

To get the desired behavior to re-use an alert message that has been "dismissed", you'll have to remove your `data-dismiss` and respond to the click event on the close button to `slideUp` or `hide` the element. Then your subsequent `slideDown` code will find the DOM elements successfully.

**[EDIT]** Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/de4qkoe5/